# Laravel sqlite migration - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: sqlite, laravel-4, phpunit

I have setup in-momory testing in laravel 4 using sqlite. using setUp and tearDown methods, I get an integrity constraint violation error for this migration (guess its because of not being able to reset):

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('test', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('id', true);
            $table->integer('other_id')->nullable()->index('other_id_idx');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Error occurs coz of the ->index('other_id_idx').

The error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fa
  ils
```

Comment: You get message about `foreign` constraint so it doesn't has nothing to index... Check other table with foreign key set.

Comment: This post should actually be an edit to your [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481976/laravel-4-phpunit-run-migration-seeding-once-for-whole-test-suite)

Comment: @FilipKoblański : i only get this error while migrating in sqlite. migrates just fine in the main db :|

Comment: @Rotwang : i seprated these 2 questions coz here i want to know why the index is causing an error when using in-memory testing. and the post u referenced, want to know how to do things only once per suite/per class - and not for every test.